# nltk cant interpret grammar category PRP$ output by stanford parser

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to generate sentence from grammar retrived from stanford parser, but NLTK is not able to interpret PRP$.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser
from nltk.grammar import CFG
from nltk.parse.generate import generate

sp=StanfordParser(model_path='/home/aman/stanford_resource/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/stanford-parser-3.4-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz',path_to_jar='/home/aman/stanford_resource/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/stanford-parser.jar',path_to_models_jar='/home/aman/stanford_resource/stanford-postagger-full-2014-08-27/stanford-postagger-3.4.1.jar')
sent1='He killed the tiger in his pants'
parse_result=sp.raw_parse(sent1)
grammar_list=[]

for p in parse_result:
    l=p.productions()
    grammar_string='\n'.join(map(str,l))
    grammar=CFG.fromstring(grammar_string)
    #grammar_list.append(grammar)
    #for s in generate(grammar,n=3):
    #    print s




ValueError: Unable to parse line 11: NP -> PRP$ NNS
Expected a nonterminal, found: $ NNS
```

how can it be worked.Should i specifically instruct nltk for these grammar categories.

Comment: `CFG.fromstring()` expects a grammar, but you give it a tree instead (the parser's output). I don't think this can be "made work", at least not easily.

Comment: grammar_string is a string as 

           `ROOT -> S
           S -> NP VP
           NP -> PRP
     PRP -> 'He'
     VP -> VBD NP PP
     VBD -> 'killed'
     NP -> DT NN
     DT -> 'the'
     NN -> 'tiger'
     PP -> IN NP
     IN -> 'in'
     NP -> PRP$ NNS
     PRP$ -> 'his'
     NNS -> 'pants'`


which is nothing but a input grammar

Comment: The problem is with CFG.fromstring() not accepting `$` in non-terminal names. You should clean up the code and add the definition of `grammar_string` to your question, otherwise it's non-sensical.

Comment: This should give you a genera, solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43038238/937153

Answer (score 5):

> ValueError: Unable to parse line 11: NP -> PRP$ NNS
>   Expected a nonterminal, found: $ NNS

I've no idea why you are trying to combine a hand-built CFG with the output of the Stanford parser, but here's a solution to this problem:

I quick inspection of `nltk/grammar.py` shows that `$` is not a legal character for a non-terminal name. This can be easily corrected by patching the module like this:

```
import nltk
import re
nltk.grammar._STANDARD_NONTERM_RE = re.compile('( [\w/][\w$/^<>-]* ) \s*', re.VERBOSE)
```

In the above I just added `$` to the regexp that you'll find in `nltk/grammar.py`. You can then create and use grammars that have `$` in their productions:

```
grammar = nltk.grammar.CFG.fromstring("NP -> PRP$ NNS")
```