# Generating PCFG from Universal tagset

Tags: python, nltk, grammar

I am trying to build a PCFG using the POS tags obtained from the below code:

```
from nltk.corpus import treebank

corpus = treebank.tagged_sents(tagset='universal')
tags = set()

for sent in corpus:
    for (word, tag) in sent: 
        tags.add(tag)

tags = list(tags)
print tags
```

Gives,

```
['ADV', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'PRON', 'DET', '.', 'PRT', 'NUM', 'X', 'CONJ', 'ADJ', 'VERB']
```

I need to generate a PCFG using the POS tags above. But, when I try to construct a grammar using the rule

```
nltk.grammar.PCFG.fromstring("""T5 -> . NT6 [0.136235]""")
```

it produces

```
ValueError: Unable to parse line 1: T5 -> . NT6 [0.136235]
Expected a nonterminal, found: . NT6 [0.136235]
```

I assume that the exception indicates that "." is not a valid non-terminal in `nltk.grammar.PCFG`. But I am wondering if there is a neat way to fix this.

**Related**

[nltk cant interpret grammar category PRP$ output by stanford parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207799/nltk-cant-interpret-grammar-category-prp-output-by-stanford-parser) gives a nice fix to add '$' from treebank tagset to the grammar. But then again treebank POS tagset contains single quotes (' ') as a POS tag, which is not a valid symbol.

Is there a neat work around for this problem without having to add each special character to the grammar?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207799/nltk-cant-interpret-grammar-category-prp-output-by-stanford-parser) shows how to tweak the CFG syntax to accept additional characters in the non-terminal names. (`PCFG` inherits from `CFG`).

Comment: But your self-answer seems like the best approach for *your* use case: No reason to wrap your grammar into a string just to parse it again.

Comment: @alexis: Thanks for pointing it, but I have already included that post in the description

Comment: I overlooked the link, sorry. But did you read the answer and **add the single quote** to the regexp? There should be no difference between the handling of `$` and `'`. Yeah, I know, "without having to add each special character". But the tag names are a limited set, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @alexis: Well, that is true. It wasn't a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer to this question. Instead of using `fromstring` method, generate PCFG object by passing a list of `nltk.ProbabilisticProduction` objects and an `nltk.Nonterminal` object as below:

```
from nltk import ProbabilisticProduction 
from nltk.grammar import PCFG
from nltk import  Nonterminal as NT

g = ProbabilisticProduction(NT('TS'), [NT('.'), NT('NT6')], prob=1)

# Adding a terminal production
g = ProbabilisticProduction(NT('NT6'), ['terminal'], prob = 1)

start = NT('Q0')  # Q0 is the start symbol for my grammar
PCFG(start, [g]) # Takes a list of ProbabilisticProductions
```